# Checking Duplicates Numbers In Array c++

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple C++ program that finds how many duplicates are in the array.

This works perfectly for me but this is very long code. And I would like to know if there is any short code which may perform this task successfully:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a[10];
int reper=0,word=0,flage=0,number[10]={
    0
};
//Getting Input From User
for (int i = 0; i <=9; i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter The Value For "<<i<<" Index"<<endl;
    cin>>a[i];
}
//Checking The Duplicates Numbers
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    reper=0;
    flage=0;

    for (int j = 0; j <=9; j++)
    {
        if (a[i]==a[j])
        {
            if (i!=j)
            {
                reper++;
            }
        }
    }
    number[i]=a[i];
    for (int k = 0; k <=9; k++)
    {
        if (i!=k)
        {
            if(number[i]==number[k])
            {
            flage=1;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    //If There Are Duplicates Then Prints That Numebr, How Many Times It Repeated And Total Occurance Of That Number In The Array
    if (reper!=0&&flage==0)
    {
        cout<<"Repeated Number Of The Array Is  : "<<a[i]<<" ";
        cout<<"And This Number Repeated "<<reper<<" Times "<<"And Total Occurance Of This Number is : "<<reper+1<<endl;
        word=a[i];
    }
}
//If There Is Nothing Any Duplicate In The Array Then Simply Prints This Message On Console
if (reper==0&&word==0)
{
    cout<<"There Is Nothing Any Repeated Number Of This Array: "<<endl;
}
system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question asks for a shorter way and thus is basically asks for a [codereview.se].

Comment: This will be a good question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the easiest way to implement this - using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset. It has logarithmic complexity and inner methods to count repeated items. 
Refer an example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::multiset<int> ms;

    //Getting Input From User
    for (int i = 0; i <=9; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter The Value For "<<i<<" Index"<<std::endl;
        int val;
        std::cin>>val;
        ms.insert(val);
    }

    bool repeated_number_found=false;

    std::multiset<int>::const_iterator it = ms.begin();
    while (it != ms.end()) {
        int reper=ms.count(*it);
        if (reper > 1){
            std::cout << "Number " << *it << " repeated for " << reper << " times" << std::endl;
            repeated_number_found=true;
        }
        it = ms.upper_bound(*it);
    }

    if (!repeated_number_found){
        std::cout<<"There Is Nothing Any Repeated Number Of This Array"<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But using this container you will loose first entrance of repeated number, if it matters to you, I will recommend using struct or std::pair to hold entrance number with entered number. In this case you will need to provide custom comparator also (refer to doc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to achieve this would be to sort the array and do something like this :-

(include the header file algorithm before doing this.)

```
vector <int> a (10,0);
for (int i = 0; i <=9; i++)
{
  cout<<"Enter The Value For "<<i<<" Index"<<endl;
  cin>>a[i];
}
int count = 0;
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
for(int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
if (a[i] == a[i + 1]) {
    count++;
   }
}
cout << count << endl;
```

Comment: That's the practical way, and is O(N log N). However you can do it in O(N) time by using a hash table.

Comment: Hi Rahul, 
Thank you so much for answering my question.
But I'm facing problems when I try to compile your given code.
I get the error at this line
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
I have added the algorithm header file already.

Comment: try using sort(a.begin(),a.begin()+10);

Comment: try using sort(a.begin(),a.begin()+10); and (include header file vector).